# Как сделать редактор текста на сайте в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Например, у меня есть блог, и чтобы добавить новость, мне нужно текст заключать в теги. Но когда я вывожу новость, то Laravel не распознает теги.Как сделать так чтобы laravel распознавал теги, или может есть готово решение редактирование текста, может похожее как здесь на Stackowerflow  .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По умолчанию весь выводимый контент экранируется, т.е. все элементы и сущности HTML показываются как есть, вместо того, чтобы обрабатываться браузером. Если вы не хотите, что бы данные экранировались, используйте следующий синтаксис:

```
Hello, {!! $name !!}.
```

Т.е. в переменной `$name` может быть следующий код:

```
<script> alert('Name'); </script>
```

Но, как сами понимаете - это не безопасно, т.к. я могу добавить `while`, тем самым "сломать" сайт..

```
<script> while(1) alert('Name'); </script>
```

[Подробнее.](http://laravel.su/docs/5.0/templates)

**UPD**

Даже на [офф сайте](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade) сказано:

> Blade `{{ }}` statements are automatically sent through PHP's
>   [`htmlspecialchars` function](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to prevent **XSS attacks**.

Comment: Примечание: Будьте осторожны с выводом контента, который получен от пользователей. Всегда используйте двойные фигурные скобки для экранирования возможных элементов и сущностей HTML. Это как? можно пример.

Comment: @АнтонПивоваров, ну например, при регистрации в поле **Имя** пользователь мог ввести этот скрипт. И потом при выводе имени пользователя как автора поста или что-то другое вы можете попасться на эту уловку и скрипт будет исполняться *(может даже и у каждого пользователя, если пост могут видеть все)*. По-этому стоит выводить через `{{ }}`, пример: `{{ $post->text }}`.

Comment: @АнтонПивоваров то есть смысл в том что **{!! $name !!}** использовать лучше на контенте которому вы полностью доверяете (либо который вы внести сами, либо либо который проходит дополнительную обработку на xss), а вот **{{ $name }}** сделает эти проверки за вас.

Answer (score 2):

При выводе используйте

```
{!! $name !!}
```